# Adding modal when clicking a hyperlink

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink

I want to load a modal using custom directive when a hyperlink is clicked. but the thing is that hyperlink already defined a ng-click function. Current ng-click function also should work my requirement. How can I do it without changing the ng-click function? Below is my hyperlink.

`<a href="#" class="book-btns add-to-cart" data-ng-click="service.addToCart(hotel)" >Add to cart & Continue> </a>`

Answer (score 0):

`href="javascript:;"` should work to disable the default link behaviour.

Comment: No I don't want to disable current one. I want it to work also while working my solution (if there is)

Answer (score 0):

Create the custom directive so that it binds to "click" on the element.